# add column from raw df to groped df in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Hello I have created grouped dataframe from raw dataframe with this command:

```
sp2 = spark_df.drop_duplicates().groupBy('Transaction').agg(F.collect_list("Product").alias("items"))
```

and my `spark_df` dataframe has three columns: `Transaction`, `Products` and `CustomerID`

I want to put `CustomerID` column into the `sp2` dataframe ( it wont be grouped).

When I try to join it with this command:

```
df_joined = sp2.join(spark_df, "CustomerID")
```

I got this error message:

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o44.join. :
>   org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: USING column `CustomerID`
>   cannot be resolved on the left side of the join. The left-side
>   columns: [Transaction, items];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs because you don't have `CustomerID` column in your `sp2` dataframe. so you can not join them on `CustomerID`. I suggest you to create a `CustomerID` column with `None` value in `sp2` dataframe and then join it with `spark_df` on `CustomerID` column.

This is a sample code to do this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

sp2 = sp2.withColumn('CustomerID', f.lit("None").cast(StringType()))

df_joined = sp2.join(spark_df, "CustomerID")
```

**UPDATE**: The other way to add `CustomerID` column into your grouped data is to use `first` function:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

sp2 = spark_df.drop_duplicates().groupBy('Transaction').agg(F.collect_list("Product").alias("items"), F.first('CustomerID').alias('CustomerID'))
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, but now I got this error: Detected implicit cartesian product for INNER join between logical plans

Comment: Is there any way to put that column into grouped dataframe?

Comment: I think it is because the `CustomerID` is not the first column. change the code like this, and try again joining. `sp2 = sp2.select('CustomerID', 'Transaction', 'items')`. and join like this: `df_joined = sp2.join(spark_df,  "CustomerID", how='full')`

Comment: can I select CustomerID while creating grouped dataframe with  this command: sp2 = spark_df.drop_duplicates().groupBy('Transaction').agg(F.collect_list("Product").alias("items"))

Comment: Did you try `sp2 = spark_df.drop_duplicates().groupBy('Transaction', 'CustomerID')` to put `CustomerID` in your grouped data?

Comment: Yes I did but then count of the result changed, I am not sure if it is right or not

Comment: another way is: `sp2 = spark_df.drop_duplicates().groupBy('Transaction').agg(F.collect_list("Product").alias("items"), F.first('CustomerID').alias('CustomerID'))`

Comment: I think this works because count didn't change. If you write it alternative answer, I will accept. Thank you